# What is that diamond/cone formation in the Satisfactory promo?

Tags: satisfactory

One of the promo images found on the [Steam Page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/526870/Satisfactory/) shows an almost diamond/cone shape formation in the middle of a mess of conveyer belts with a structure ontop of it

[image: Diamond formation]

i haven't explored the entire world yet but of what i have seen i have never came across anything like it yet.

So i am wondering what it is? if it's a natural land formation or something man made (out of what if we know) and where in the world is it depicted as being located at?

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of the conveyor elevators seemingly attaching to it, it's just a ton of conveyor belts arranged in an upward spiral fashion, similar to as seen in [this video](https://youtu.be/X77MHTOEwXo?t=332).

Apart from looks, I wouldn't say this is a particularly inefficient design, and it seems like your computer will take quite the resource hit from building such a structure.

Comment: I also just noticed that in the top right of the image, the contributor is "Let's Game it Out", who is also the creator of the video I linked to. So I would say there is a *really* good chance that structure is what I described.

Comment: Yeah, Let's Game It Out is a person who breaks games for the fun of it. I should know, I'm a fan

Comment: Yeah, "Let's Game It Out" is a quirky youtuber who made his name for "playing the games wrong". Satisfactory naturally encourages order, efficiency, responsibility in the gameplay. so obviously his playstyle is utter chaos. All the neon-green objects on the conveyors? Nuclear waste, it harms you if you get close. It should be recycled or at least stored far away from anywhere you visit. Not hauled all around the map on conveyors. The purpose of that giant tower is to trigger people with OCD about how nonsensical and pointless it is.

Answer (score 2):

Lets Game It Out made it in his video.
It is not a thing in the game and wont spawn.
(everything he does is a spectacle, so if you see his name disregard it)